# convert docx to (x)html with absolute position of words

Tags: html, xhtml, docx

Is there any way to convert a docx document into (X)HTML where each word is positioned with position:absolute using CSS code?
I am interested in reproducing in a website exactly the same pagination I see in the document. If not with position:absolute, is there maybe another way to do it?

Comment: try this [link](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html)

Comment: @Cyzanfar, I know about Calibre, but I have not found a way to force it to output absolute word positions, is there?

Comment: you are looking for your text to be exactly formatted the way it is in your docx?